# Is the shell's `source` POSIX-standard?

Tags: shell, unix, posix

I've spent some quality time searching the [POSIX standard for the shell](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/utilities/xcu_chap02.html) for the `source` and `.` commands, and am at this point convinced that they're just not in there.

Are there any shells that don't support the `.`? What is the POSIX-standard way of executing a shell script in the current environment (i.e., not spawning a subshell, so if the script says `export VAR=value` then `VAR` exists in the calling shell)?

I might be missing something obvious, but it turns out that `.` is not very easy to Google...

Comment: The C shell family of shells is unlikely to support `.` as a synonym for `source` which is their native way of writing the same operation.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It's there under ["dot"](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#dot).

> **NAME**
>
> dot - execute commands in the current environment
>
> **SYNOPSIS**
>
> . *file*

[etc.]

Comment: Yes, the `.` command is standard. But do note that the `source` alias available in bash and some other modern shells is *not* part of POSIX.

Answer (score 27):

`.` is standardized (POSIX [2004](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/utilities/dot.html), [2008](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_18_01)).

`source` is non-standard and specifically not supported in `ash`, `dash` or `pdksh` (so probably it's not in the original Korn Shell either). I.e., it's a Bashism.

Comment: The C shell used `source` instead of the `.` that was used by the Bourne shell.  The Korn shell used `.` to be compatible with the Bourne shell.  It was imported into `bash` for reasons that are not clear, but it makes C shell migrants feel at home, and is easier to index than `.` [dot](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#dot).